# Markov's paper on insolubility of the homeorphy problem

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, computability

I am looking for an English translation of Markov's 1958 paper, *On insolubility of the homeorphy problem*, which I remember coming across on a website for a computational topology course (taught by Afra Zomorodian).

Comment: Aleksandr Aleksandrovich Markov, The insolubility of the problem of homeomorphy,
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 121 (1958), 218–220.

I'm guessing that version isn't in English?

Comment: The paper seems to exist in English, but not for free. Project Euclid and JStor seem to have it.

Comment: If you are affiliated with a university, and you've had no luck, I've discovered that the best people to ask about this are librarians (at least if there is a math library). My school had an automated system for submitting requests for papers. It was supposed to be things that were inaccessible otherwise, but once they found the paper for me on arXiv and sent a link.

Comment: Thanks, I may try that. I remember this URL (graphics.stanford.edu/~afra/goodies/markov.pdf) was accessible in very recent past (three months or so ago), however, it seems I didn't download the paper.

Comment: Hi. Did you get it eventually? If so can you share it with me?

Comment: Well, sort of. I managed to find a physical print of the PDF which I downloaded a long time ago, from graphics.stanford.edu/~afra/goodies/markov.pdf, and scanned it. So what I have is several megabytes of scans, not very high quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here on Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240050509_Insolubility_of_the_problem_of_homeomorphy) you can read it.

In footnote there is written that it was translated from German by Afra Zomorodian, so it is the same thing that were in the dead link you remember (graphics.stanford.edu/~afra/goodies/markov.pdf).

I also printscreened this 5 pages and put them in one [PDF file](https://pl.scribd.com/doc/294974140/Markov-Insolubitily-of-the-Problem-of-Homeomorphy)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is the document mentioned in the question.