# Can anyone explain this paper :? " The world problem: on the computability of the topology of 4-manifolds"

Tags: general-topology, computer-science, computability

Link to the paper is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0506019.pdf

The author explains that the problem of determining if two 4-manifold are related by a homeomorphism is undecidable. And that this is unique to four dimensions.

Can someone construct a sketch, and explain why it doesn't work in other in other dimensions. Or at least why it doesn't work in another dimension as an example.

Comment: I skimmed the paper, but I'm reading it as saying that the problem is undecidable in $n$ dimensions whenever $n \geq 4$.  I'm not familiar with the topological undecidability result.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Either the author is mistaken or you are misinterpreting what they say: The homeomorphism problem is undecidable for compact manifolds of all dimensions $\ge 4$ (this is what Markov proves in his original paper). In dimension 2 it is easily decidable (mostly Euler characteristic). The fact that it is decidable in dimension 3 is quite hard, too hard for a sketch. Lastly, I suggest you do not trust a physicist to get math details right.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well here they seem to suggest it is only in 4 dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold#Topological_4-manifolds "For any finitely presented group it is easy to construct a (smooth) compact 4-manifold with it as its fundamental group. As there is no algorithm to tell whether two finitely presented groups are isomorphic (even if one is known to be trivial) there is no algorithm to tell if two 4-manifolds have the same fundamental group." Or is it a slightly different problem?

Comment: This observation is the key (but not enough!) for Markov's theorem. But the same construction works in all dimensions. You can find Markov's original paper in a link given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451931/markovs-paper-on-insolubility-of-the-homeorphy-problem?rq=1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Isn't there something unique in 4-manifold in regards to computability. Is it classification of smooth manifolds that is uniquely non-computable in 4 d, or something else? I recall Frederic Schuller mentioned something is his video series.

Comment: @Anon21: Nothing unique that I know of (among manifolds of dimension $\ge 4$). As I said, read Markov's paper if you do not trust me.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I believe you, I just checked the paper and it says n>3. wikipedia seems to suggest that n=4 has a difference between its topological and differential classification, whereas n>4 they are the same.

Comment: @Anon21 No, the difference between smooth and topological starts in dimension 4. Of course, dime suin 4 is special in other ways, but not in regard to the algorithmic homeomorphism problem. One caveat: For the problem to make sense, manifolds have to be represented in a finitary fashion, which usually means a triangulation.