Reference for "Classifying topological spaces up to homeomorphism is impossible"
On the Wikipedia page it is stated that there is no algorithm that classifies manifolds up to homeomorphism because of the "word problem". And therefore one can deduce that classifying topological spaces up to homeomorphisms is at least as difficult.
In the references of the Wiki page I have looked through the books. But I have not found anything that references exactly that statement. Does anyone have a reference for that?

You'd have to decide on an input encoding for "classifying topological spaces up to homeomorphism" to make sense.

Are you asking for a reference for the undecidability of the triviality problem for groups, or for the fact that any finitely presented group can be realised as the fundamental group of a 2-complex?

@NaïmFavier References for both would be best. However, I would be glad for any reference

It is Markov's theorem, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326870/can-anyone-explain-this-paper-the-world-problem-on-the-computability-of-th

@MoisheKohan Thanks! That is what I was looking for.
